Why is a Microsoft Graph response telling me that there is no Location Header set?
In my ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application, I am using Microsoft Graph to get a list of members of an Azure Active Directory group. The authentication used is Microsoft Entra.
How come when I try to call the Graph API in my controller, this error gets thrown?

Exception: No header present in response with status code Found
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to perform redirect as Location Header is not set in response

How can I set the location header?
public async Task<dynamic> GetGroupMembers(string groupId)
{
    try
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzureGovernment
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(configuration["TenantId"], configuration["ClientId"], configuration["ClientSecret"], options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        // this is where the error gets thrown
        var members = await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.GetAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return null;
}

So far I have used Microsoft's documentation on how to create a graph client using the Tenant ID, Client ID, and Client Secret provided by my security team. I have also set my client credential to use the Azure Government host. Microsoft Graph Client
The group ID I am trying to get members of is the application's assigned group, which was set by security in the Azure Portal. I am able to get the group's ID through my claims since I am a member of the group.

Could you please add the whole stack trace?

Could you pls change the the scope url? We can see from this section, Ms Graph API url for US government is https://graph.microsoft.us which is not .com
